# Android - Honeycomb - Action Bar tab fragments save/restore state

Tags: android

In the docs it says to ensure you save a fragment's state when using tabs with the action bar so that when you switch tabs the fragment will look as it did before. How is this done? Using the sample for handling tabs, onSavedInstanceState is not called when the tab is switched so where would I save the state? Do I do it at the activity level? I only want the state to be transient.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fragment.onSaveInstanceState() is the proper place.  That will be called when the state needs to be saved.  If it isn't called, it doesn't need to be saved yet.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. If you use the sample way of handling tabs, the fragment manager removes the fragment when you unselect the tab and adds the fragment when you select the tab. If you have a ListFragment when you go back to its tab it does not even remember where in the list you were. Pre-3.0 if you had activities in tabs their state was remembered by the system. I am trying to do the same in HC but onSavedInstanceState is not called.

Comment: onSaveInstance state is only called if the fragment is completely removed. For example if you change the screen orientation. If you want to save something at the moment the tab is removed from the layout overwrite onPause in the fragment that is shown if the tab is selected.

Comment: How do I get the updated bundle to come through the onActivityCreated block if I store it in onPause -- I can't call setArgument because the fragment is still active

Comment: You store your stuff in onSaveInstanceState() to get it back when later created.  If your fragment is not being re-created, the same object is there, so you can just use your member variables.

Comment: What would be the proper way of restoring Fragment state when switching between tabs with minimum Android support to API12 level? As level platform v3.1 do not have such methodes as FragmentTransaction.Atach/Detach fragments?! onSaveInstanceState()  is not called when the tab is switched.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem and came up with a solution that feels redundant (I assume this functionality will work better down the line), but it does work.  The solution is to manage state bundles manually via the activity.

Saving state: In each fragment, implement a function called something like getState() that will return a bundle containing whatever state data the fragment wants to save.  The activity should then call that before removing the fragment from the view.

Restoring state: Implement a method or constructor in the fragment that accepts the same bundle it saved before, and unpack the bundle to be used however it makes sense for the fragment. When the activity adds the fragment back to the view, pass the bundle in that the fragment earlier provided, and you should be set.